# Чем обрабатывается код - Node.js или javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

Всем привет.

Я +- новичек в области программирования.
(Сам верстальщик сайтов.)
Недавно начал изучать(по курсам + чтение документации) технологии:
`vue.js, vue-router, vuex, nuxt.js` и меня интересует следующие моменты:

Если я делаю сайт на всех этих технологиях то:

1) Мой код обрабатывает `node.js` или же нативный `javascript`?
(Где это можно отследить? Какими инструментами?)

2) На сколько я понимаю проект можно развернуть в 3-х режимах в `nuxt.js`:

а) `static`.

б) `universal`.

в) `spa`.

Вопрос:
Правильно ли я понимаю что в первом случае после деплоя - проект будет обрабатыватся нативным `js`,
В 3-м на `node.js` 
и во 2-м будет какой то гибридный вариант?

3) Если мне требуется работать с текстовыми файлами(с большими объемами по 250 мегабайт и более) то как лучше всего это делать?
(Нативным `js` или через `node.js` или может есть еще какие то вариант встроенные в `nuxt.js` или какие то другие технологии `vue`?)
В данном случае я имею ввиду простое считывание текстовых строк с их последующей обработкой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы немного не правильно ставите вопрос, дело в том что `NodeJS` ничего не обрабатывает, грубо говоря, `NodeJS` это расширенный синтаксис `JS`, а вот этот синтаксис, исполняет движок обработки `JS` под названием `Google V8`. Этот движок стоит в основе исполнителя в браузере `Google Chrome` и в основе `NodeJS`, просто адаптация  `V8` под "ноду" дает нам использовать расширенный `JS`, а именно такие модули как `request`, `file` и т.д.

Если ваш код выполняется в браузере, он выполняется браузерным `V8`, если ваш код выполняет `V8 NodeJS`, смысла в "гибридносте" нет.

И вообще, вы должны просто понять, что нет такого как "обычный ЖС, а там есть не обычный, а там есть мутант ХХХААААЛЛЛЛККК ЖС!!!", у `JS` есть не так много движков, остальное это или платформы, или фреймворки. `NodeJS` это тот же `JS` который будет исполняется тем же движком, просто с некоторым количеством улучшений и расширений.

Comment: *"NodeJS это расширенный синтаксис JS"* – что, простите? Чем это расширенный?

Comment: @D-side новыми модулями, а что, это не так? :) Вы же не одобряете `JS`?

Comment: Да, это не так. Модули (в том виде, в котором они в NodeJS) никакого отношения к синтаксису не имеют.

Comment: @D-side, модули его расширяют, так и произошло в ноде, пришло несколько новых модулей(которые реализованы внутри на плюсах) и научили работать с этими модулями `V8`.

Comment: Синтаксис? Или всё-таки функциональность?

Comment: Это две граничащие вещи. Использования файлов в ноде, это функциональность, которою нам представляют модули, а для их использования мы немного обновлён синтаксис.

Comment: Не-а. Ошибки в синтаксисе возникают на этапе разбора кода, а отсутствующая функциональность всплывает уже на этапе выполнения. Вы можете запустить код из NodeJS в браузере, если определите недостающие функции (правда, той же функциональности не факт, что добьётесь). А если бы "гипотетический диалект JS из NodeJS" был синтаксически расширен, это было бы невозможно, браузер бы не смог даже *начать* выполнять код (и, например, увидеть отсутствие функции `require`).

Comment: @D-side, ну да, в этом плане, вы правы.